# Adding `withCredentials: true` to all of my get requests in Angular 13 broke the navigate?

Tags: angular

Logging in works just fine but I have this code that should run after login. It runs, but doesn't actually redirect to the admin. I'm completely new to angular so not sure what is going on. This was working until I started using the withcredentials and using the auth cookie. This line of code `this.router.navigate(['/admin']);` is running but nothing actually happens anymore.

```
onSignInButtonClick(event: any) {
        this.hasError = false;
        this.errorMessage = '';
        this.isLoading = true;

        this.authService
            .signIn(this.username, this.password)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe.asObservable()))
            .subscribe(
                (user) => {
                    console.log('Sign in successful.');
                    if (this.authGuard.redirectUrl) {
                        console.log(
                            'Redirecting to ' +
                                this.authGuard.redirectUrl +
                                '...'
                        );
                        this.authGuard.usingAuthGuardUrl = false;
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(this.authGuard.redirectUrl);
                    }
                    else {
                            console.log('Redirecting to admin...');
                            this.router.navigate([`/admin`]);
                    
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.hasError = true;
                    console.log('error:', error);
                    this.errorMessage =
                        "The username and password combination you entered didn't work :(";
                }
            );
    }
```

Update:
More investigation I found `this.sessionService.isUserSignedIn())` is false. This is in the `AuthGuard` service. It appears that the session isn't being updated with the user info or something. Basically `canActivate` returns false. Not sure how to update this. Will keep you updated.

Comment: What do you see in console?

Comment: Redirecting to admin...

Comment: What is your current route? What is `admin` route definition? Is there any guard that can stop navigation? Have you added `enableTracing` to router options for debugging? BTW, authGuard as a class is deprecated now. It's just a plain function now. Injecting it in a component and using as service is not a good idea.

Comment: I added enableTracing and got this: `NavigationCancel {id: 2, url: '/admin', reason: 'Navigation ID 2 is not equal to the current navigation id 3'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this was a hard issue for a newbie like me to figure out. The Authguard was checking if the user was logged in. I kept getting a 200 from the server on authenticate so I know the user was logging in. The issue ended up being that since we aren't adding the session to the request body anymore the authguard was failing. It was looking for `result.session` where result was the response from the authenticate endpoint. I had to change the method that was looking for the session in the response to look for something else like the username.